# Every continuous function is Borel measurable.

Tags: measure-theory, measurable-functions

We say that $f$ is Botel measurable function if inverse image of every Borel set is again is Borel measurable.

Equivalent: $f: X\rightarrow R$ ($X\subset R$) is borel measurable set if $f^{-1}(a,\infty)$ for any $a$ is Borel measurable set.

Suppose $f:X\rightarrow R$ is continuous function. $X\subset R$. Prove that this function is Borel measurable.

1. We know that if a function is continuous then the inverse image of every open set is open.
2. Hence $f^{-1}(a,\infty)$ will be open for every $a$ in $R$.
3. Now we have that inverse image of $(a,\infty)$ (which is Borel set because it is open) is a Borel set.
4. $f$ is Borel measurable function.

Question: Am I correct? There is very different proof in my textbook. My proof is very easy. So I am sure there is big mistake in my proof. What is wrong?

EDIT: [image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: This is correct, but maybe your book is using a different definition of "Borel measurable". Could you give at least an outline of the proof in your textbook?

Comment: @DaveL.Renfro I added pics

Comment: I think the difference comes from the fact that your book is using the $\ \epsilon$-$\delta\ $ definition of continuity, while you're using the (more general) definition that $\ f\ $ is continuous if $\ f^{-1}(A)\ $ is open for every open $\ A\ $.  While the definitions are equivalent in contexts where the first one makes sense (i.e. metric spaces), using the second one in this context makes the proof simpler.